# How to align an SVG button inside a form

Tags: html, css, forms, svg

I try to create a form that contains two inputs and a button. Instead of a text button, I would rather use an SVG instead, but it doesn't align properly.

Suppose the following CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  margin: 25px;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  fill: #bbb;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  fill: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <button type="submit">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <path d="M384 512h-320v-128h320v-128l192 192-192 192zM1024 0v832l-384 192v-192h-384v-256h64v192h320v-576l256-128h-576v256h-64v-320z" />
   </svg>   
 </button>
</form>
```

When you run the snippet, then the input fields are aligned at the bottom, but the SVG-button is aligned to the top. If I replace the SVG with a text, then it aligns fine.

Comment: An easy solution: add `form{display:flex}` and make sure the svg and the inputs have the same height.

Comment: display:flex; will not work in all devices I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to align `button` itself next to `input`s. we're using `vertical-align: middle` on every element inside `form` to achieve the same goal.

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  margin: 25px;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 2px;
}

form * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  fill: #bbb;
}

button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  fill: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <button type="submit">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <path d="M384 512h-320v-128h320v-128l192 192-192 192zM1024 0v832l-384 192v-192h-384v-256h64v192h320v-576l256-128h-576v256h-64v-320z" />
   </svg>   
 </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Just Add **vertical-align: middle;** to your selector.

```css
body {
  background: #222;
  margin: 25px;
}

form {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  padding: 2px;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  background: #444;
  color: #ddd;
  margin-left: 6px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

input:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #666;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: transparent;
  margin-left: 6px;
  height: 23px;
  width: 23px;
  fill: #bbb;
  /*Just add this line to your target element to align in the middle*/
  vertical-align: middle;
}
svg{margin:auto;}
button:focus {
  outline: 0;
  fill: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="email" id="email" />
  <input type="password" id="password" />
  <button type="submit">
   <svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
    <path d="M384 512h-320v-128h320v-128l192 192-192 192zM1024 0v832l-384 192v-192h-384v-256h64v192h320v-576l256-128h-576v256h-64v-320z" />
   </svg>   
 </button>
</form>
```